# Confused with the ? operator in C#

Tags: c#

I have a variable called full_name if the full_name has a string length > 5 I would like to set nm to the first 4 characters of full_name otherwise I would like to set nm to all the characters of full_name.

```
var nm;

if (full_name.Length > 5)
{
    nm = full_name.Substring(0, 4);
}
else
{
    nm = full_name;
};
```

I'm totally confused with the "?" operator.

Could I use it for this ?

Comment: Btw, by name that is the "conditional operator"

Comment: or even sometimes called "ternary operator" (somewhat incorrectly)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Comment: @yas4891 yes, it is commonly misnamed that :) that is like calling `+` "a binary operator" - it only tells you the signature, but not the intent. Now... We just need a few more ternary operators to act as examples...

Comment: I have opened up pandora's box by that remark - haven't I ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var nm = full_name.Length > 5 ? full_name.Substring(0, 4) : full_name;
```

Comment: JudyJ: Needs no further explanation as Marc has solved it (literally!), but you can read up this article at MSDN purely from a academic perspective. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=VS.100).aspx